# Xamarin Essentials Emailattachment

Tags: xamarin, email-attachments

My application needs to attach a text file to email. When I attempt to create an email attachment I throw a "System.InvalidOperationException".

I have permissions set to read/write external storage. I have variously tried storing the attachment in "FileSystem.CacheDirectory" and "System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData". In both cases I can write/read the file. I went to the page "Xamaein.Essentails: Email" and tried thier example. I can send the email if there is no attachment, but trying the attachment example throws the same exception. Can someone tell me what I have missed??

Comment: please show the relevant code

Comment: Code from Xamarin Essentials Email that  I copied and pasted                       
             var message = new EmailMessage
{
    Subject = "Hello",
    Body = "World",
};

var fn = "Attachment.txt";
var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fn);
File.WriteAllText(file, "Hello World");

message.Attachments.Add(new EmailAttachment(file));

await Email.ComposeAsync(message);

Comment: which platform are you testing on?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer. The EmailAttachment class is experimental. Inserting this line

ExperimentalFeatures.Enable("EmailAttachments_Experimental");

before the

"message.Attachments.Add(new EmailAttachment(file));"

line will make it work.